# Running process on a remote browser

Tags: ssh

I work on remote machine using the ssh protocol.

I try to test a tool which is a process running on the port 5000.

Code:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4386/python
```

To visualise this process, I have to launch on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ on the browser.
My question: how can I access to the remote browser or how can link it with my local browser ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ssh tunneling to forward port 5000 of the remote machine to your local machine. In order to achieve this, ssh to the machine as follows:

```
ssh -L 5000:localhost:5000 <username@remotemachine>
```

Now, if something is being served on port 5000 on your remote machine, it should show up on the browser on your local machine by pointing to http://localhost:5000

Comment: ssh -L 5000:localhost:5000 <username@remotemachine> (i use this command on my machine ? )Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Yes, connect the remote machine with this command.